# What is the best option for managing tasks

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I have thousands of user's and for every one of them I have a few hundred tasks that need to be done.
Because I do not want to finish with one user and all the others will wait, what my best option to run them all at the same time so if I have user with two tasks, so he did not wait for user that has 100 tasks, and of course, if there user that enters the queue but he in 100 place, for example, so I do not want him to wait for all the 99 users before him to finish.
What's my best option doing that in JAVA?

Thanks.

Comment: where the tasks come from?

Comment: Your question is unclear. are you using queus? what kind of tasks you need to perform on users (users perform the task, or are you performing task on users?!)?

Comment: The scheduling is not clear. From your question, it seems like every user should have its tasks done as soon as possible, which is of course not possible. Decide if you want to use FIFO, or assign priorities to tasks for example. Both are possible.

Comment: Sorry did not explain myself well.
When I create new user I first need to create for each of his friends an animation that can take 1-3 seconds to create, and he can have 1 to thousands friends. After that I need to create scheduling that update once a week all these animations for each user.
I do not like that each user needs to wait until the user before him will finish with the creation of his animations friend, especially that there users that have 1000 friends, for example, and their users that have 10 friends.
What does the treatment in this situation?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Threads.

I suggest you run a diffrent thread for each user, that way a user with only few thread will not wait for others to finish.